# Magento 2 accidental theme move

Tags: magento2, theme, xml

I FTP'd into my server with filezilla. I accidentally moved one theme into another. I have since moved it back but now its pulling in the footer from its parent theme, luma. Default.xml and Default Head Blocks.xml aren't working either.

I'm in developer mode.

Do I need to clear a folder?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The move altered the db. Under the "Theme" table it changed my physical theme to a virtual theme. 0 to 1 value. I changed it back and ran php70 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

I think when you have by mistake moved theme directory in another directory in database create a virtual theme. so just go to the database in set your theme and remove virtual theme.

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure your theme from the backend once again.
Then run the following commands.

```
rm -rf var/* generation/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```